# LIKE in SQL Lite Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

My Code is :

```
find = "https://example.com"
sqlite_select_query = "SELECT * FROM 'table' where links LIKE (?)"
c.execute(sqlite_select_query, (find,))
```

what is the problem? i want when i Select something, Code filter the result for me, when i run this code it returns `[]` 
and when im trying to add % at the first and the end like :

```
"SELECT * FROM 'table' where links LIKE (%?%)"
```

it gives me an operational error, what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: `c.execute(sqlite_select_query, ('%'+ find + '%',))`

Comment: Thank you, Problem solved @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

You must use the concatenation operator `||` like this:

```
find = "https://example.com"
sqlite_select_query = "SELECT * FROM 'table' where links LIKE '%'|| ? || '%'"
c.execute(sqlite_select_query, (find,))
```